# Lua : How to compare two json/tables and report on the differences?

Tags: json, lua

I hope someone can help me with this -

I make a number of API calls to various services, all of which return a structured JSON response. Normally I just convert to a table, and extract the one or two values i need, but I’d really like to be able to do a full comparison check to see everything that’s changed since I retrieved the last one.

I’ve already gone down the path of writing a block of code to specifically compare each entry within the associated tables generated, (I’m on Lua version 5.1) but I wanted to ask is there a more dynamic way of doing this, one which is not so rigid that I could even apply against any other json calls (2 x Lua tables) i want to compare?

*(I’ve looked at various SO posts about comparing Lua tables but most just look to report if there’s a difference overall (true/false), none of them seem to itemise the differences, or can adapt to different json/table structures -  which is important considering the variety of json structures API services return)*

Below is an example api json/response, and a sample of the code I’ve written to compare an entry in both tables and report the differences…

Is there a dynamic version that can do the same thing, avoiding the need to script in detail, every comparison step ?

```
local json = require("dkjson")
local snapshot1 = [[
{
   "ActTime" : 1501360852,
   "ServerTime" : "2017-07-29 22:40:52",
   "Sunrise" : "05:50",
   "Sunset" : "21:28",
   "result" : [
      {
         "AddjMulti" : 1.0,
         "AddjValue" : 0.0,
         "BatteryLevel" : 255,
         "Data" : "73 Lux",
         "Description" : "",
         "HardwareID" : 4,
         "HardwareName" : "Dummies",
         "HardwareType" : "Dummy",
         "ID" : "82089",
         "LastUpdate" : "2017-07-29 21:16:22",
         "Name" : "ESP8266C_Licht1",
         "Notifications" : "false",
         "ShowNotifications" : true,
         "SignalLevel" : "334",
         "Timers" : "false",
         "Type" : "Lux",
         "YOffset" : "0",
         "idx" : "89"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK",
   "title" : "Devices"
}
]]

local snapshot2 = [[
{
   "ActTime" : 1501360852,
   "ServerTime" : "2017-07-31 11:40:52",
   "Sunrise" : "05:52",
   "Sunset" : "21:29",
   "result" : [
      {
         "AddjMulti" : 1.0,
         "AddjValue" : 0.0,
         "BatteryLevel" : 255,
         "Data" : "73 Lux",
         "Description" : "",
         "HardwareID" : 4,
         "HardwareName" : "Dummies",
         "HardwareType" : "Dummy",
         "ID" : "82089",
         "LastUpdate" : "2017-07-30 21:16:22",
         "Name" : "ESP8266C_Licht1",
         "Notifications" : "false",
         "ShowNotifications" : true,
         "SignalLevel" : "545",
         "Timers" : "true",
         "Type" : "Lux",
         "YOffset" : "0",
         "idx" : "89"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK",
   "title" : "Devices"
}
]]

local tableA = json.decode(snapshot1)
local tableB = json.decode(snapshot2)
if tableA.ActTime ~= tableB.ActTime then
    print("ActTime has changed from [ "..tableA.result[1].ActTime.." ] to [ "..tableB.result[1].ActTime.." ]") end
if tableA.ServerTime ~= tableB.ServerTime then
    print("ActTime has changed from [ "..tableA.ServerTime.." ] to [ "..tableB.ServerTime.." ]") end
if tableA.result[1].LastUpdate ~= tableB.result[1].LastUpdate then
    print("result:LastUpdate has changed from [ "..tableA.result[1].LastUpdate.." ] to [ "..tableB.result[1].LastUpdate.." ]") end
```

As always, many thanks to this community for their help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are JSON tables, we can make the following assumptions greatly simplifying the problem of comparing two tables:

1. There are no cycles, backreferences, duplicate references etc.; the object is a proper tree;
2. Tables are either dictionaries/objects (string keys) or arrays/lists (integer keys from 1 to `n`, possibly holes depending on how your JSON library handles `null`s)
3. Values are either booleans, numbers, strings, or one of the aforementioned two table types

we can now write a recursive function that returns the difference in table form:

```lua
local function table_changes(original, modified)
    if original == modified then return nil end -- no changes
    if not (type(original) == "table" and type(modified) == "table") then return {from = original, to = modified} end -- primitive types
    local result = {}
    for k, v in pairs(original) do
        result[k] = table_changes(v, modified[k])
    end
    for k, v in pairs(modified) do
        if original[k] == nil then
            result[k] = table_changes(nil, v)
        end
    end
    return next(result) and result -- return nil for an empty table (no changes)
end
```

this will return a table like the following:

```lua
{
    ServerTime = {
        from = "2017-07-29 22:40:52",
        to = "2017-07-31 11:40:52"
    },
    Sunrise = {
        from = "05:50",
        to = "05:52"
    },
    Sunset = {
        from = "21:28",
        to = "21:29"
    },
    result = {
        {
            LastUpdate = {
                from = "2017-07-29 21:16:22",
                to = "2017-07-30 21:16:22"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @LMD wow, this is great, thank you so much ! I wish I could see the solution to these things as easy as you and others on this forum do :-) . QQ: Considering the assumptions you’ve made,  Is there theoretically no limit to the size / complexity of the json response (Lua table) that I could be run through this ?

Comment: @nodecentral this should run in linear time O(n + m) in the sizes n, m of the two JSON objects.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to deserialize the JSON string and compare the resulting table element by element.

Expanding mentioned solutions that just deliver true/false so something that lists the differences is trivial.

table fields can be added, removed or changed. This is just a matter of comparing two tables recursively.

Comparing the json strings would be much more complex.

Comment: Hi @Piglet, is the json.decode call used in my code, a form of deserialisation ? As it results in a Lua Table ?

Comment: yes exactly. and encode serializes

Comment: Thanks, and i don’t know how many table to table compare SO posts I looked at but most just worked on basic arrays, or didn’t seem to go very deep. Is there an example you were thinking of ?

Comment: the art of programming is not knowing many SO posts. learn the basics and you can solve any problem yourself. LMD already gave you an example so why do you need me to provide another one?

Comment: LMD did an amazing job and that really helped me out. You on the other hand set me off to learn, and there’s nothing wrong with that. But I’m not a developer, and  with multiple jobs, I can only try to learn all this on the side, also I personally work best with real world working examples, that I can deconstruct  and learn how it works it to my needs. As you know to learn any language, repetition is key, sadly that requires time, which I wish I had more of.  i  really appreciate the help people like you and LMD provide, I know many of Lua basics in my head, frequency of use is my issue :-(

Comment: I assure you learning the language and doing stuff yourself will be much faster than searching examples for hours long term.

Comment: Totally agree, but to learn and retain things successfully it requires dedication, repetition and regular usage. Sadly 3 elements a lot of people don’t have in abundance :-( . I’m sure like many others who use SO, we have pockets of time to invest in learning / trying things like this which we love, but cannot commit to, or change our careers for. Hence the patience and support from those can and do, is why I keep coming back. If a proven level of time commitment was required to post on this site I would probably fail and would lose the ability to scratch my Lua itch (which makes me happy :-))